# How can a user diagnose Active Directory account lockout?

Tags: active-directory

After changing my password for my Active Directory account at work, I experience regular account lockout as if I had entered in the wrong password a bunch of times. This will happen after I've successfully logged in. I know there are tools for AD Admins to diagnose what is causing the lockout, but my IT department has been unhelpful. I've already updated the password on all services and Outlooks I'm aware of. I've cleared Credential Manager. I'm at a loss.

Are there any tools for a normal user to diagnose which machine and process is triggering the account lockout?

Comment: There are tools that exist, they are useless to a normal user, your AD Administrators can assist you with this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I said as much in the question

Comment: With access to the event logging on the DCs, it'll be hard to pinpoint which computer is locking you out. The most likely case is that you're still logged into some system, and when you change your password, that system you're still logged into is causing you to be locked. You need an AD Administrator to help you figure that out.